# why doesnt my .py file work in windows but works perfectly fine in the PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, file, pycharm, ide, window

im a new programmer and i've written a simple code to close my friends PC. Ive got the code working in the idea but when ever i tried to open in in the :D/ file it never works. the code has afew imported packages which i think are the problem but cant be sure. ive tried to search it up in youtube and ive tried running it from the command prompt but no use. What should i do

```
import pyautogui as pyautogui
import random
import keyboard
import time

def auto():
    pyautogui.moveTo(10,1070,3)
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    pyautogui.move(0,-50)
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    pyautogui.move(0,-100)
    pyautogui.doubleClick()

for i in range(1):
    auto()
```

ive tried search it up in youtube to find a solution and ive also tried opening in from the command prompt. idk what else should i have done

Comment: Please show how `"it never works."`. Do you mean when using `cmd`? Do you get some sort of error message?

Comment: do you double-click on it ?

Comment: Quamrana, when I said it never works I meant that it opens a terminal and closes it in a millisecond. I waited for a few seconds to see if it would do anything and nothing happened.

Comment: Yes Azro i have double clicked it many times.

Comment: Do you want to double click on an icon/file somewhere, or could you instead manually open `cmd` and run the program from there?

Comment: I've done both run it on the cmd of the respected directory and double clicked it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the same Python environment that you are using with PyCharm (and where you installed pyautogui).

Pycharm activates that environment automatically, so you should do the same when you run your command.

You can use python.exe from your virtual-environment to run your .py file and then it should work fine.

PS. there are also a couple of things out of place on your code: you can remove the `range(1)` and the `as pyautogui` for example.

Comment: When you said " Python environment " , can you explain to me what that really is ?

Comment: @oweet - you can read more about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

In Pycharm you'll see that as "interpreter" in settings... and it will tell you what the path of the virtualenv Python interpreter is

Answer (score 0):

I find windows very difficult to work with because of the environment variables and registry settings needed to automatically open a file with a given program. (Especially as I keep upgrading python as new versions are released)

I have settled on creating a folder to work in for each project with a batch file, called `setpython.bat` like this:

```
@echo off
path = C:\Python310
```

(Or the relevant path to the requisite python installation)

Then I open `cmd` and navigate to this folder and run: `setpython`

Now I can run any of my python programs there with: `python <file>.py`